# dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused

Tags: firefox, flask, connection-refused

I have hosted a flask web application and when I try to open it from the Firefox browser it says "**dial TCP 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused**". But when I try to open the URI in chrome it works fine. What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 9):

You must be using VPN in your browser. That's why you are unable to access app with localhost.

Try disconnecting the VPN.